# ¿Por qué deberia usar const en c++?

Tags: c++

He visto que usan `const` en métodos en c++, pero no entiendo por que

En este caso supongo que el compilador me avisara si intento modificar el puntero

```
void DrawTga(const Tga *tga, int x, int y) const;
```

Pero en este caso no entiendo

```
void DrawTitle(Renderer &renderer, const std::string &title) {

    TextWriter title_writer(ScreenMarginX, ScreenMarginY - TitleFontSize - 10,
                            renderer, false, TitleFontSize);
    title_writer << title;
}

//Código extraído de linthesia
```

https://github.com/linthesia/linthesia/blob/master/src/MenuLayout.cpp

Se supone que un parámetro recibe una copia, no importaría que modifique el valor.
Tampoco me queda claro que significa el & en este caso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿Porque debería usar `const` en C++?

Para cumplir con las normas de la corrección<sup>1</sup> constante, conocidas en inglés como "*Const correctness*". A grandes rasgos se puede resumir de la siguiente manera: *Todo aquello que no debe ser modificado, debe ser constante*.

La corrección constante tiene una triple función<sup>2</sup>:

1. Permite al compilador tomar decisiones de optimización sobre el código cuando puede asumir que algunas partes del código no van a cambiar.

   ```
   const int valor = 0;

   if (valor)
       std::cout << "Valor: " << valor << '\n';
   ```

   En el código anterior, el compilador podría<sup>3</sup> decidir eliminar todo el `if` ya que nunca se va a cumplir.
2. Añade un significado al código que toma la función de documentación implícita.

   ```
   void funcion(const std::vector<Objeto> &elementos);
   ```

   Con solo consultar los parámetros, sabemos que la función `funcion` no va a modificar la colección `elementos` ni ninguno de los objetos que ésta contiene.
3. Aumenta la seguridad del código al añadir más control sobre las operaciones que se pueden realizar.

   ```
   struct Contador {
       void Incrementa() { ++val; }
       int Consulta() const { return val; }
   private:
       int val{};
   };

   const Contador c;
   c.Incrementa(); // Error, no se permite modificar el objeto
   ```

---

Veamos el caso que no entiendes:

> ```
> void DrawTitle(Renderer &renderer, const std::string &title) {
>
>     TextWriter title_writer(ScreenMarginX, ScreenMarginY - TitleFontSize - 10,
>                             renderer, false, TitleFontSize);
>     title_writer << title;
> }
> ```
>
> Se supone que un parámetro recibe una copia, no importaría que modifique el valor.

Para empezar ¿Tú esperarías que una función que pinta un texto modificase dicho texto? Imagina que vas a una empresa de rótulos y pides un cartel con tu nombre "[*Carlos*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/114621/carlos)" pero te entregan uno con el mío "[*PaperBirdMaster*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster)" ¿Te parecería razonable que la empresa te dijera que ha cambiado el texto del cartel porque no les habías dicho que no pudieran cambiarlo?.

Ese es un ejemplo de corrección constante a nivel de documentación, no hay motivos para modificar el parámetro `title`, así que no hay motivos par que dicho parámetro sea modificable; marcándolo como constante informas a cualquier usuario de la función que dicha función no va a cambiar el contenido de ese parámetro.

Para acabar, el parámetro lo está recibiendo como referencia constante, no por copia. Pero en este caso es un tipo especial de constante. Las referencias constantes tienen la habilidad de extender el tiempo de vida de valores temporales:

```
std::string Patata() { return "Patata"; }

int main()
{
    std::string &a = Patata();
    const std::string &b = Patata();

    std::cout << a << '\n'
        << b;

    return 0;
}
```

Observa que la función `Patata` devuelve un objeto `std::string` temporal (construido al vuelo en la sentencia `return`) en el código anterior la variable `a` se queda apuntando a un objeto que ha dejado de existir (era temporal) pero la variable `b` extiende el tiempo de vida del objeto retornado por `Patata`.

Pasa algo parecido en la función `DrawTitle`, dado que recibe una referencia constante, puede recibir tanto parámetros existentes como parámetros construidos al vuelo:

```
std::string PaperBirdMaster("PaperBirdMaster");
DrawTitle(r, "Carlos");        // std::string construido al vuelo.
DrawTitle(r, PaperBirdMaster); // std::string pasado por referencia.
```

Si el parámetro `title` fuese una referencia no constante, no podrías pasarle un `std::string` temporal (construido al vuelo).

---

<sup>1</sup>Segunda acepción de la palabra [corrección](https://dle.rae.es/correcci%C3%B3n?m=form): *Cualidad de correcto*.

<sup>2</sup>Los ejemplos son absurdamente sencillos por brevedad, su único objetivo es entender la utilidad de la corrección constante en diferentes contextos, no son un ejemplo práctico.

<sup>3</sup>Todas las decisiones del compilador dependen del compilador en si y de la configuración que esté usando, por eso las expreso en condicional.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no sé cual es el motivo del uso de una constante en los ejemplos que pones, pues solo pones el prototipo y no la definición de la función. Supongo que se trata de un [literal de cadena](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) (adjunto la documentación a C, por que no los suelo ver con strings de C++). En resumen, un literal de cadena es una secuencia de caracteres no modificables con el carácter nulo al final (`\0`). Usas un literal de cadena como primer arguneto de `printf` en C, y también los usar para inicializar un array de caracteres.

```
char char_array[] = "Hola mundo!";
```

A esta cadena se le asigna el carácter nulo al final automáticamente, también se puede hacer los mismo con un puntero `char`.

Creo que deberías usarlo cuando solo cuando requieres de una cadena de solo lectura, y usar un string mutable (ya sea de C o C++) cuando ocupas modificar la cadena. Por ejemplo el prototipo de [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

Si te fijas, ocupa un literal de cadena como delimitador, mientras ocupa un string mutable como la cadena a cortar. Al menos en C, si le pasas un literal de cadena como primer argumento a `strtok()` vas a obtener falla de segmentación. Me refiero a:

```
strtok("Esto es un string","y esto el delimitador");
```

Hay que aclarar dos cosas muy importantes,

1. No es lo mismo iniciar un array `char` con un literal de cadena, que con caracteres individuales. Pues este último es mutable, a diferencia del otro.
2. Los literales de cadena, siempre van rodeados por **comillas dobles** (`""`).

Obviamente, no sé cual fue le motivo de la persona que escribió el prototipo de esa función para poner `const`. Supongo que nada más ocupaba el contenido del string y no modificarlo en sí.

Comment: En una cadena de char * tiene mas sentido que en un std::string porque no podria modificar el valor original aunque quisiera, a menos que use un puntero.

Comment: De cualquier modo, se busca indicar que el valor solo se va usar con propósitos de lectura, y no se va a modificar dentro de la función.